# data.table: NA blurs unlist type

Tags: r, data.table

I have an unknown list as a column in a `data.table`.  In the case below that column is `z` and it's a character column or will be.  However the first two elements of the list are `NA`s which are logical.  When I try to `unlist` the `z` column I get the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dat, , .(z = unlist(z)), by = x) : 
  Column 1 of result for group 2 is type 'logical' but expecting type 'character'. Column types must be consistent for each group
```

This is because I'm mixing logical (`NA`s and `character`).  I could coerce as follows: `dat[, .(y = as.character(unlist(y))), by='x']` but the problem is `z` is unknown.  How can I make the presence of `NA`'s not throw the error in a generalizable way?

```
library(data.table)

dat <- data.frame(
    x = 1:3,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

dat[['y']] <- list(1:3, 5:6, 18:19)
dat[['z']] <- list(LETTERS[3:6], NA, LETTERS[13:16])
setDT(dat)

dat[, .(z = unlist(z)), by = x]
```

Comment: I guess we can use `NA_character_` and it should work fine. i.e. `dat[['z']] <- list(LETTERS[3:6], NA_character_, LETTERS[13:16])`

Comment: @akrun yet but this has to be generalizable.  It's in a function that doesn't know what type is being passed.

Comment: Is it possible to check the type in the `list` and then change the `NA` accordingly?  Otherwise, convert all 'NA' to character and then change it to real NA later..

Comment: Yes but that seems like a lot of monkeying around.  If I unlist outside of data.table it coerces the vector to the least restrictive.  I'd want that behavior.

Comment: You could also use Amanda's package for this which seem to handle it properly, something like: `library(splitstackshape) ; res <- listCol_l(dat, "z")` Or you can just do `dat[, .(z = as.character(unlist(z))), by = x]` (which will need further attention I guess if you don't want it necessarily a character class)

Comment: @DavidArenburg You could post that as a solution.  The options looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `unlist` and then `relist` to make the `'NA' in a compatible format

```
dat$z <- relist(unlist(dat$z), skeleton=dat$z)
setDT(dat)
DT <- dat[, .(z = unlist(z)), by = x]
DT$z
#[1] "C" "D" "E" "F" NA  "M" "N" "O" "P"
is.na(DT$z)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

Or another option is to replicate the 'x' column by the `length` of each `list` element in 'z' and `unlist` the 'z' column.

```
dat[, .(x=rep(x, lengths(z)), z=unlist(z))]
```

Comment: This works.  I'll wait to see if there's othe rapproaches.